# Localize stimulsoft report in designer

Tags: javascript, localization, stimulsoft

I'm using stimulsoft Reports.JS .

How can I localize my report in the stimulsoft Report Designer ? ( Without hardcoding my strings in JS ) ? People are talking about some "Globalization Dictionary" but I can't find it. You can see a live demo of the Designer here :

http://js.stimulsoft.com/designer.html?reportname=SiteStatistics&themename=Teal&localization=en

Answer (score 0):

The "Globalization dictionary" is in the report properties ( If you have the report designer in another language, click "Report Tree", the third tab button in the bottom of the page, click on the report, and click on "Properties", the first tab button in the bottom of the page, and then you will find the Globalization dictionary in the second part of the properties ).